# How to debug Android app that has login with Google+?

Tags: android

I develop an android app that has a login form using Google+. The problem is everytime I want to debug the app after modify the codings, I need to generate signed APK, and manually installed to tablet, then debug the app. If not doing like that, GoogleSignInResult result.isSuccess always return false. However, doing like that, at most of the times it will return false. Sometimes it return success. It depends on luck. So how to properly debug this app?

Answer (score 0):

U can't debug signed Apk... U can get log messages through txt file.

Call below method wherever u want like in onActivityResult print  requestCode, responseCode

```
private void log(String message) {
    File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"log.txt");
    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter=new FileWriter(file,true);
        fileWriter.append(message);
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```